# Past due approval tasks to show rejected (how to)

Tags: workflow, approval-process, design

Hope someone can help me on this. 
I have created an approval workflow in Sharepoint Designer wherein the results could be approved or rejected. What i want to do is when a task/approval is past due the outcome defaults to rejected. Hoping to get some guidance on how i can make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are building this in Power Automate, so I'll tell you what I would do there. I would start and approval but not use the start and wait for approval card, just the start approval card. Then I would put a separate wait for approval card into a do until control with the condition set to "utcNow() greater that TaskDueDate." I haven't tested this yet, but it should cause the flow to wait for the approval as long as the current date isn't beyond the due date of the task in planner. Then you can configure it to do whatever you want after that if the approval does come or doesn't. You can just play with the run after setting on the step after the do-until to get it to do whatever you want. Hope this helps!

Comment: Apologies for not specifying but im doing this in sharepoint designer